# PHP Getting Media Information From A Remote File

Tags: php, ftp, media

So here's the setup. I'm storing and streaming videos on my website. I have a web server where most of the interaction is done and a media server which stores and streams the video files.

I'm trying to write a script on the web server that will list out all of the videos on the media server and get all the information about each video.

I can use the `ftp` commands through `PHP` to get the list of files on the media server without any problem. What I am looking to do is also get media information from each remote file such as video duration, codec, bitrate, etc. Not sure if this is possible, but if anyone knew how, it would be someone here on StackOverflow.

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
$conn = ftp_connect($media_server) or error_out('Failed to connect to FTP server');
ftp_login($conn, $username, $pwd) or error_out('Failed to login to FTP server');

$files = ftp_nlist($conn, ".") or error_out('Could not retrieve list of files');

foreach($files as $file){
    $return[] = array('file_name' => $file,
              'file_size' => ftp_size($conn, $file));;
}

ftp_close($conn);

echo json_encode($return);

exit();

function error_out($text){
    echo '{ "error":"'.$text.'" }';
    exit();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried the class `getID3` at http://getid3.sourceforge.net/ but unfortunately it does not support remote files. The files have to be on the same server.